# Removing duplication from Spring controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, refactoring

I have been looking for a way to somehow reduce the amount of code that is duplicated with subtle variance in my Spring MVC controllers, but searching through the SO questions so far has only yielded some questions without any satisfactory answers.

One example of duplication that I want to remove is this, where the user creation page and the role creation page share similarities:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "user/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String create(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult errors) {
    LOG.debug("Displaying user creation page.");
    return "user/create";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "role/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String create(@ModelAttribute("role") Role role, BindingResult errors) {
    LOG.debug("Displaying role creation page.");
    return "role/create";
  }
```

A slightly more involved variant of duplication that I would like to remove is the one for posting the create form:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "user/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String save(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult errors) {
    LOG.debug("Entering save ({})", user);
    validator.validate(user, errors);
    validator.validatePassword(user, errors);
    validator.validateUsernameAvailable(user, errors);
    String encodedPassword = encoder.encode(user.getPassword());
    user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
      return create(user, errors);
    } else {
      service.save(user);
    }
    return "redirect:/user/index/1";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "role/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String save(@ModelAttribute("role") Role role, BindingResult errors) {
    LOG.debug("Entering save({})", role);
    validator.validate(role, errors);
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
      return create(role, errors);
    } else {
      service.save(role);
    }
    return "redirect:/index";
  }
```

This example includes a validate then save if correct and a redirect to the error page if things don't go as planned.

How to remove this duplication?

Comment: This problem may happen working with Spring, Spring MVC or using other framework. You're looking for code refactoring techniques to apply in your current code.

Comment: I am aware that this problem may happen in other contexts as well, however I feel that due to Spring's processing of the RequestMapping annotations, this question does not fit well into standard extract to super class, or extract to method solutions.

Comment: did u try tiles http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-tiles

Comment: @constantlearner As far as I know Tiles is a view technology. I am currently using Freemarker for that. Can you please provide some context as to why you think changing the view would help in this particular problem?

Comment: Since you're new to SO, you should use `@username` when replying somebody in comments. Example: @constantlearner check the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would provide the solution that I settled on in the hope that it might help someone. My gf suggested that I use the name of the entity as a path variable for the controller, and this has proved to provide a very nice solution for the problem at hand.

The two methods now look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{entityName}/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String create(@PathVariable("entityName") String entityName, @ModelAttribute("entity") BaseEntity entity, BindingResult errors) {
  LOG.debug("Displaying create page for entity named: [{}]", entityName);
  return handlerFactory.getHandler(entityName).getCreateView();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "{entityName}/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@PathVariable("entityName") String entityName, @ModelAttribute("entity") BaseEntity entity, BindingResult errors) {
  LOG.debug("Saving entity of type {}", entityName);
  CrudHandler handler = handlerFactory.getHandler(entityName);
  handler.getCreateValidator().validate(entity, errors);
  if (errors.hasErrors()) {
    return create(entityName, entity, errors);
  }
  handler.preSave(entity);
  handler.getService().save(entity);
  return "redirect:" + DASHBOARD_URL;
}
```

The `CrudHandler` interface has implementations for each entity, and provides the controller with the entity specific classes that it needs, such as service and validator. A sample `CrudHandler` implementation looks like this for me:

```
@Component
public class RoleCrudHandler implements CrudHandler {

  private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "role";
  public static final String CREATE_VIEW = "role/create";
  public static final String EDIT_VIEW = "role/edit";
  @Resource
  private RoleService roleService;
  @Resource
  private RoleValidator validator;
  @Resource
  private CrudHandlerFactory handlerFactory;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    handlerFactory.register(ENTITY_NAME, this);
  }

  @Override
  public GenericService getService() {
    return roleService;
  }

  @Override
  public Validator getCreateValidator() {
    return validator;
  }

  @Override
  public Validator getUpdateValidator() {
    return validator;
  }

  @Override
  public BaseEntity createEntity() {
    return new Role();
  }

  @Override
  public void preSave(BaseEntity entity) {
  }

  @Override
  public String getCreateView() {
    return CREATE_VIEW;
  }

  @Override
  public String getUpdateView() {
    return EDIT_VIEW;
  }
}
```

If someone sees some ways to improve this, feel free to share. Hope this will be of use for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses your handler method parameter types to create class instances from the request parameters or body. As such, there is no way to create a handler (`@RequestMapping`) method that could take an `Object` and check if it is either a `Role` or a `User`. (Technically you could have both parameters and just check which one isn't `null`, but that is terrible design).

Consequently, you need a handler method for each. This makes sense since, even through the logic is similar, it is still specific to the exact type of model object you are trying to create. You perform different validation, call a different service method, and return a different view name.

I say your code is fine.

Comment: While the logic is specific to each class, if this were a regular class, I would have considered moving things to a generic super class for some variation of Strategy/Template method. The Spring annotations do make this cumbersome though. :(

Comment: @vtanase `@Controller` annotated classes are just regular classes. You can make them generic or extend from generic classes. But, i don't see how you would make that code more readable or more maintainable. You can split your handler methods across controllers, one for `User`, one for `Role`.

Comment: it would make the code more readable since the logic would only be in one place, for example the second case only varies in validation and a post validation processing. Everything else is identic, the error check, the redirect to the error page, I would prefer to have it all in one place.