# How to Remove Repeated code in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a bunch of controllers where I include the following

```
public class AController{
@GetMapping
public List<A> getallA() {...}

@GetMapping("/{index}")
public A getA(Long index){...}
}
```

and then that is repeated

```
public class BController{
@GetMapping
public List<B> getallB() {...}

@GetMapping("/{index}")
public B getB(Long index){...}
}
```

Is there a way to remove the repeated code through a custom annotation? Perhaps, a generic implementation? I have never done this so the help would be very helpful. Ideally it would be something like

```
@GetFunctions(A.something)
public class AController{
}
```

Comment: Do `A` and `B` have same parent?

Comment: Not currently, they could I suppose

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do something like pass name of the parameter as a path variable it will work try like the below example,
[Removing duplication from Spring controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771081/removing-duplication-from-spring-controllers)

If you want to have @RequestMappings with multiple values of attributes,

```
@RequestMapping({ "/index", "/contact" })
```

you can use like the above code snippet